# Как динамически добавить параметр в форму и отправить ее в новое окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, javascript-events

Имеется форма с полями.
В нее добавлена кнопка и скрытый чекбокс.

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку, добавить к форме параметр со значением и отправить форму в новое окно.
Другими словами, форма работает с фильтрами и разными кнопками и чекбоксами, и нельзя на постоянной основе добавлять в нее поля, иначе она перестанет выполнять функции админки. Но необходимо отправить флаг который можно перехватить в коде и поменять логику, в моем случае сделать выгрузку данных.

Проблема: Если использовать click, то при нажатии на кнопку, форма постится и данные выгружаются. Но чекбокс остается помеченным, что ломает работу админки.

Если использовать mousedown и mouseup, то параметр чекбокса не улетает на сервер.

Что тут можно придумать?

Код кнопки и обработка:

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-phone">
    <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" >Экспорт</button>
    <input class="element-invisible" type="checkbox" name="export" value="export-items" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !(function() {

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#export-btn').on('mousedown', function(event) {

                //event.preventDefault();
                var element = $(this).closest('div.btn-group').find('[type="checkbox"]');                       
                $(element).prop('checked', true);

            });

            $('#export-btn').on('mouseup', function(event) {

                //event.preventDefault();
                var element = $(this).closest('div.btn-group').find('[type="checkbox"]');                       
                $(element).prop('checked', false);

            });

        });

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor Есть кнопка, есть чекбокс. При клике помечаем чекбокс, он улетает на сервер вместе со всеми параметрами. Но он остается отмеченным, а надо снять пометку сразу же как форма запостилась. Как ее снять, по какому событию?

Comment: Теперь понял :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо ничего помечать и отпомечать. Уберите чекбокс. Добавьте в кнопку `name` и `value`.

```
<button id="export-btn" name="export" value="export-items" class="btn btn-success" 
  type="submit" formtarget="_blank">Экспорт</button>
```